# Don't compile when there are bad bindings

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

Is there a way to prevent a WPF project from compiling in Visual Studio when there are bad/incorrect bindings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, bindings are evaluated at runtime using reflection.  There is no way that I am aware of to force validation at build time.  Because a view can be bound to any model type when the application is active it is designed to "fail gracefully" when a binding can't be evaluated.  You can see these failures in the output window as (typically) red debugger output lines.